# How to integrate $\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin^nx}{\sin^nx+\cos^nx}dx$?

Tags: integration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I calculate $\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin^3 t}{\sin^3 t+\cos^3 t}dt$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82489/how-can-i-calculate-int-0-pi-2-frac-sin3-t-sin3-t-cos3-tdt)

How can we integrate $$\int_0^\frac{\pi}2\frac{\sin^nx}{\sin^nx+\cos^nx}\,\mathrm dx , \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, n\in N \quad?$$ Thanks for any hint.

Comment: I saw this question before. The first time I saw it it was a bit trickier. It said evaluate $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{1+\tan^n(x)}dx$

Comment: sir Amr you saw it but i dont saw it before i posted my question i search in this site and  cant find it because these question has different form  (i m not trickier)

Comment: @ Maisam Hedyelloo I didnt mean this! I saw it before in a book called "The art and craft of problem solving" (and not in this site). I was just saying a different form of the problem.

Comment: Its OK. The copy I had, I borrowed it from my university's library.

Comment: There is the same question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82489/how-can-i-calculate-int-0-pi-2-frac-sin3-t-sin3-t-cos3-tdt?rq=1

Comment: hi @tomas : i try to find it but i cant thanks any more

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Hint:** Make the change of variable $u=\frac{\pi}{2} -x$, noting that 
$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)=\cos x$.  Then replace the letter $u$ by $x$, and the answer will hit you.

**Remark:** The hint is given in the language of formal manipulations, but the idea is purely geometric.

Comment: That answer is surely mean.

Comment: Andre-nicolas your answer is very nice thanks