# Evaluate $ \int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \frac{\sin x}{\sin x+\cos x}\,dx $ using substitution $t=\frac{\pi}{2}-x$

Tags: calculus, integration

This problem is given on a sample test for my calculus two class. $$ \int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \frac{\sin x}{\sin x+\cos x}\,dx $$ I can find the value of this integral using other substitutions which lead to partial fractions but the prof added a hint to use the substitution $$t=\frac{\pi}{2}-x $$ so I've been trying to figure out how to do it his way but am pretty lost. Any ideas?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82489/how-can-i-calculate-int-0-pi-2-frac-sin3-t-sin3-t-cos3-tdt/82493#82493

Answer (score 10):

**Hint:** Do the substitution, and stop.  You will get that our integral is equal to another integral over the same interval. Add them!

Symmetry solves problems.

Answer (score 4):

HINT: $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}2-x\right)=\cos x$, and $\cos\left(\frac{\pi}2-x\right)=\sin x$. Look at the sum of your original integral and the new one.

Answer (score 4):

$I = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin x}{\sin x+ \cos x}\mathrm{d}x$. On the other hand, with the substitution $t = \frac{\pi}{2} - x$, we obtain
\begin{align}
I & = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin (\frac{\pi}{2}-t)}{\sin (\frac{\pi}{2}-t)+ \cos (\frac{\pi}{2}-t)}\mathrm{d}t \\
& = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos t}{\sin t+ \cos t}\mathrm{d}t \\
& = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos x}{\sin x+ \cos x}\mathrm{d}x \\
\end{align}
as $\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-t) = \cos t$ and $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-t) = \sin t$.

Adding the "original" form of $I$ and this new form, we have
\begin{align}
2I = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin x + \cos x}{\sin x+ \cos x}\mathrm{d}x = \int_0^{\pi/2} \mathrm{d}x = \frac{\pi}{2},
\end{align}
from which we obtain $I = \frac{\pi}{4}$, and say to ourselves, "Hmm that is cool."

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy way to solve. Let
$$ A=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin x}{\sin x+\cos x}dx, B=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos x}{\sin x+\cos x}dx. $$
Then
$$ A+B=\frac{\pi}{2} $$
and
$$ A-B=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin x-\cos x}{\sin x+\cos x}dx=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{-d(\sin x+\cos x)}{\sin x+\cos x}=-\ln(\sin x+\cos x)\big|_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}=0. $$
From this, we have
$$ A=B=\frac{\pi}{4}. $$
Generally, I can use this method to compute (for $a,b>0$)
$$ A=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin x}{a\sin x+b\cos x}dx, B=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos x}{a\sin x+b\cos x}dx. $$
It is easy to see
$$ aA+bB=\frac{\pi}{2} $$
and
\begin{eqnarray*}
aB-bA&=&\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{-b\sin x+a\cos x}{a\sin x+b\cos x}dx\\
&=&\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{d(a\sin x+b\cos x)}{a\sin x+a\cos x}\\
&=&\ln(a\sin x+b\cos x)\big|_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\\
&=&\ln a-\ln b.
\end{eqnarray*}
From this, we have
$$ A=\frac{a\pi-2b\ln\frac{a}{b}}{2(a^2+b^2)},B=\frac{b\pi+2a\ln\frac{a}{b}}{2(a^2+b^2)}. $$

Comment: You should be able to see just by symmetry that the two integrals are equal.  The symmetry comes from a simple trigonometric identity.

Answer (score 0):

**Rationalization**
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin x}{\sin x+\cos x} \cdot \frac{\cos x-\sin x}{\cos x-\sin x} d x \\
& =\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin x \cos x-\sin ^2 x}{\cos 2 x} d x\\&= \frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin 2 x-(1-\cos 2 x)}{\cos 2 x} d x\\
& =\frac{1}{2}  \left[-\frac{1}{2} \ln (\cos 2 x)-\frac{1}{2} \ln (\sec 2 x+\tan 2 x)+x\right]_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}  \\
& =\frac{\pi}{4}
\end{aligned}
$$