# integral question help me please

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^1 \frac{f(x)} {f(x)+f(1-x)}dx$$
Thank you very much

Comment: Same trick as here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82489/how-can-i-calculate-int-0-pi-2-frac-sin3-t-sin3-t-cos3-tdt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use $x\to 1-x$:
\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^1 \frac{f(x)} {f(x)+f(1-x)}dx\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{f(1-x)} {f(x)+f(1-x)}dx
\end{align}
hence 
\begin{align}
2I=I+I&=\int_0^1 \frac{f(x)} {f(x)+f(1-x)}dx+\int_0^1 \frac{f(1-x)} {f(x)+f(1-x)}dx\\
&=\int_0^1 dx=1
\end{align}
therefore $I=\frac12$.

Answer (score 3):

Let's try substitution $y=1-x$:
$$
I=\int_0^1 \frac{f(x)}{f(x)+f(1-x)}dx=\int_0^1 \frac{f(1-y)}{f(1-y)+f(y)}dy;
$$
hence,
$$2I=\int_0^1 \frac{f(x)+f(1-x)}{f(x)+f(1-x)}dx=1\Longrightarrow I=\frac12$$