# Find $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{1+\tan(x)^{\sqrt{2}}}dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Find $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\dfrac{\pi}{2}} \dfrac{1}{1+\tan(x)^{\sqrt{2}}}dx$.

I am told I should solve this by switching the limits, but I am unsure of the substitution I should use.

Comment: This is very similar to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82489/how-to-compute-int-0-pi-2-frac-sin3-t-sin3-t-cos3-tdt). The same technique applies here.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/605673/integrate-int-0-pi-2-frac11-tan-alphax-mathrmdx/605713#605713

Answer (score 1):

You may observe that, by the change of variable $x \to \pi/2-x$, you get
$$I=\int_{0}^{\dfrac{\pi}{2}} \dfrac{1}{1+\tan(x)^{\sqrt{2}}}dx=\int_{0}^{\dfrac{\pi}{2}} \dfrac{1}{1+\frac1{\tan(x)^{\sqrt{2}}}}dx=\int_{0}^{\dfrac{\pi}{2}} \dfrac{\tan(x)^{\sqrt{2}}}{1+\tan(x)^{\sqrt{2}}}dx
$$ giving
$$
2I=I+I=\int_{0}^{\dfrac{\pi}{2}} \dfrac{1}{1+\tan(x)^{\sqrt{2}}}dx+\int_{0}^{\dfrac{\pi}{2}} \dfrac{\tan(x)^{\sqrt{2}}}{1+\tan(x)^{\sqrt{2}}}dx=\int_{0}^{\dfrac{\pi}{2}} dx=\frac{\pi}{2} 
$$
 or
$$
I=\color{blue}{\frac{\pi}4}. 
$$

Comment: Substitutions are typically taught using variable other than that being integrated with respect to. Thus this answer would be easier to understand if it said let $u = \frac{\pi}{2} - x$

Comment: @TannerCarawan Then $u$ is a new "dummy" variable, which we can change back to $x$.  So, we save ourselves a step by enforcing the substitution $x\mapsto \pi/2 - x$.

Comment: Olivier.   First, Happy New Year.  Now, I am just curious.  I posted my answer to this question nearly one month ago.  And today, my answer received two down votes?  Did you experience something similar?  - Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV Thanks. Happy New Year to you. "Did you experience something similar?": yes. Please have a look at my reputation points.

Comment: If both you and I received multiple down votes today, then it makes me wonder if there is a system error.

Comment: It's not only us. I thought it was someone with some malicious intent...

Answer (score 1):

Let $I(\alpha)$ be given by

$$I(\alpha)=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{1+\tan^{\alpha}x}\,dx \tag 1$$

Then, let $x \mapsto \pi/2-x$ so that $\tan (\pi/2 -x)\mapsto \cot x$, $dx \mapsto  -dx$, and the limits of integration go from $\pi/2$ to $0$.  Then we have

$$I(\alpha) = \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\tan^{\alpha }x}{1+\tan^{\alpha }x}\,dx \tag 2$$

Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$ and dividing by two reveals that

$$I(\alpha)=\frac12\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1+\tan^{\alpha}x}{1+\tan^{\alpha}x}\,dx=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

which is independent of $\alpha$!

Comment: Why did this receive two down votes after nearly one month after I posted it???  - Mark

Comment: Shall I delete my answer then? - Mark