# How should I integrate $\cos^{2018}(x)/\sin^{2018}(x)+\cos^{2018}(x)$?

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I am working on a kind of tricky integral problem that I found online.

$$\int \frac{\cos^{2018}(x)}{\sin^{2018}(x)+\cos^{2018}(x)}dx$$

I tried substitution which changed it to

$$ \cos^{2018}(x) \ \to \sin^{2018}\left(x+\frac\pi2\right) $$

but after this substitution, I am quite uncertain how should I deal with
$$\int \frac{\sin^{2018}\left(x+\frac\pi2\right)}{\sin^{2018}(x)+\sin^{2018}\left(x+\frac\pi2\right)}dx$$

I tried every trig identity that I could possibly use in order to sum the integral but I am still struggling with this. How should I approach to solve this integral? It would be very nice if anyone could help with this. Thanks.

Comment: Weierstraß substitution might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution

Comment: The indefinite integral gets messy [even for much smaller exponents](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+%28cos%5E9+x%29+%2F+%28sin%5E9+x+%2B+cos%5E9+x%29+dx).

Comment: Are you sure the integration limits are not given?

Comment: You're integrating $\dfrac{1}{\tan^{2n}+1}$ which has period $\pi$. For large $n$ this is essentially a square wave.

Comment: Surely there is no nice explicit form for the indefinite integral. If you're looking for the definite integral $\int_0^{\pi/2}$, that has been asked many times before; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82489/how-to-compute-int-0-pi-2-frac-sin3-t-sin3-t-cos3-tdt) for example.